# Scala - map a value from a Map to another Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've a requirement to map a field in my RDD to another field from another map `UserDAO.users` I've tried to figure out the mapping here but can't return the `username` yet. I'm getting this in the updated map when I do  a foreach print `scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7c4c5ddd`

Here is my code snippet:

```
 rdd.map { l => {
      l.map { case (k, v) => {
        k match {
          case "a_userid" => {
            l.updated("a_username", userDAO.users.map(c => c.filter(f => f.userid == v.toInt)).map(y => y.map(e => e.username)))
          }
          case _ =>
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So basically,

`rdd` - `RDD[Map[String, String]]`

`UserDAO.users - Future[Seq[User]]` - where User is a case class

and returning the updated `rdd` - `RDD[Map[String, String]]`

--

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify the types of your variables? Specifically, `rdd` and `userDAO.users`. Also please give the type of the expected result.

Comment: @Aivean updated my question, thanks

Comment: ok, next question, how large is sequence of Users, returned by `userDAO.users`? Is there any reason to invoke it on worker nodes (via `rdd.map`) instead of materializing it beforehand?

Comment: @Aivean: `userDAO.users` is less than 2 thousand records but my rdd is approx 11 million records. Materializing the `userDAO.users` might work but thinking it might be possible to do it without blocking ?

Comment: If you expect concrete result, you have to wait (block) somewhere. How would you imagine it otherwise? Have `RDD[Future[Map[String, String]]]` or perhaps `Future[RDD[Map[String, String]]]` in the end?

Comment: @Aivean - either way, but down the line, I should be able to materialize the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your code to make it work. Please note, that it involves blocking, there is no other way to get concrete `RDD[Map[String, String]]` otherwise.

I ommitted `rdd.map` section for clarity.

First variant. I used your approach of reading users inside `map`. Please note, this is highly inefficient, as all users will be read each time per iteration, i.e. 11 million times:

```
// rdd.map ommitted
l.get("a_userid").flatMap {
  userId:String =>
    val newUserName:Option[String] =
      Await.result(userDAO.users
        .map(c => c.find(f => f.userid == userId.toInt))
        .map(y => y.map(e => e.username)),
        30 seconds
      )
    newUserName.map(l.updated("a_username", _))
}.getOrElse(l)
```

Alternative approach involves reading users to the map beforehand. That map then will be broadcasted to all spark workers. As your map is not that big, it's fine. This approach is more efficient, as you perform only single map lookup per iteration over `RDD`, which is fast.

```
val users:Map[Int, String] =  Await.result(userDAO.users
  .map(uss => uss.map(u => u.userid -> u.username).toMap),
  30 seconds
)

// rdd.map ommitted
l.get("a_userid").flatMap {
  userId:String =>
    users.get(userId.toInt).map(l.updated("a_username", _))
}.getOrElse(l)
```

**UPD**: Just for the sake of completeness, here is another asynchronous variant:

```
userDAO.users
  .map(uss => uss.map(u => u.userid -> u.username).toMap)
  .map { users:Map[Int, String] =>
      rdd.map { l:Map[String, String] =>
        l.get("a_userid").flatMap {
          userId:String =>
            users.get(userId.toInt).map(l.updated("a_username", _))
        }.getOrElse(l)
      }
  }
```

It follows the same approach as variant2, but returns `Future[RDD[Map[String, String]]]` instead of concrete result.

Comment: I thought as much but glad to have your opinion, thank you.